# Rancher private catalog version meaning?

Tags: version, config, rancher

In the [private catalog description](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/catalog/private-catalog/) of [Rancher](https://rancher.com/) the config.yml file is described as

```
name: # Name of the Catalog Entry
description: |
  # Description of the Catalog Entry
version: # Version of the Catalog to be used
category: # Category to be used for searching catalog entries
maintainer: # The maintainer of the catalog entry
license: # The license
projectURL: # A URL related to the catalog entry
```

What is the exact meaning of `version:`?

And what effects does this version specification have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version is used to specify the default version of an application when there are multiple versions available.

For example, let's say you are working on a todo application and release multiple versions v1.0, v1.1, v1.3 and v2.0.

You would create folder 0, 1, 2, 3 with different application images specified in docker-compose.yml and different app version value specified in rancher-compose.yml.

Now when you want to show v1.3 as the default selected option when deploying this catalog application, you would point version: v1.3 in config.yml.

Check out this application from the community catalog for more specific example: https://github.com/rancher/community-catalog/tree/master/templates/drone

Comment: thank you, but why isn‘t this part of the docs? what.constraibts held there and what effects do apply for the settings? how can we request a docs update?

Comment: PRs to improve the docs are always welcome :) Here is the repo for the docs: https://github.com/rancher/rancher.github.io